# Microsoft Outlook filter rules special characters: where are the docs

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm using Microsoft version, umm, errr.... no "about" entry under help.  It turns out version info is buried under File->Office Account->About Outlook (and it's not copy/pastable)

Anyway, using MS-Outlook in Microsoft 365, version "2202 Click-to-Run" (the 2202 is not a typo), when I create rules with special characters, they sometimes don't work.

Note that the same searches work in the "Search" box at the top of the main screen.

But I can't find help on rule filter special characters or syntax.  Any pointers?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question with an example? What do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: Agree with DavidPostill. Actually, it's better for our research if you provide more details about the rules.

Comment: Hi @Ben Slade! It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.